# How to find a file is available on server in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load a java script file from another server to my web page using java script code `document.write` method. like,

```
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mydomain.com/js/myscript.js'></script>");
```

But the respective path does not has the myscript.js so its throw `404 File not found error` in browser error console.

How can I predict and avoid this kind of errors?

If possible to predict the error, I will display alternative message instead of calling missed js file functions.

Comment: If your script creates some kind of object or global variable - check for that in the page you're loading script. For example if myscript.js defines "g" as global variable, check "if (g == undefined) throw some error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript to load script:

```
function onReadyState() {
    console.error("Unable to load file: "+ this.src + ". Please check the file name and parh.");
    return false;
}  

function addJS(path){
    var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.onerror  = onReadyState;
    e.src = path;
    e.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);
}

addJS('http://www.mydomain.com/js/myscript.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [**`jQuery.getScript( url [, success(script, textStatus, jqXHR)] )`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) - you can set success and error handlers in it.

Answer (score 0):

If the file requested is in your domain (as it seems from the question) just do a previous ajax call (with `HEAD` method) of that resource and check if the response status is `200` (ok) or `304` (Not modified)

Answer (score 0):

try this approach

```
   var js="ajax/test.js";

    $.getScript(js) .done(function(script, textStatus) {
          var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
          script.src = js;
          document.body.appendChild(script);;
    })
```

for more details: [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Please note: ***`Use javascript (not jQuery) to manipulate HTML DOM`***